# Google Calendar API Push Notification Not Working

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I've gone thru lot of documents on it, but didn't find anything helpful.

I'm successfully able to call

> https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars//events/watch

api and receiving expected response from watch api.

```
{ "kind": "api#channel", 
  "id": "<UUID>", 
  "resourceId": "<resourceId>", 
  "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<emailid>/events?maxResults=250&alt=json", "token": "<tokenvalue>", "expiration": "1524485589000" }
```

I believe google should start notifying to the address property (host url where we want to get notified), once above channel gets setup. But I don't receive any notification.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Thanks.

Comment: have you followed this https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push?

Comment: Yes, I followed above doc too. My domain is registered https url and I'm getting success response of channel (watch response). But I don't get any sync message notification as well as any push notification on updating any event.

Comment: Can you try looking at the official [Google Drive Push Notifications Playground](https://github.com/googlearchive/drive-pushnotifications-playground) code and demo if the concept applies to you?

Comment: Thanks for DalmTo and Noogui for the your feedbacks. I actually figured out the issue. There was no any issue with implementation. Issue was with invalid ssl certification. I was using some aws provided EB hosted environment which has invalid certification and that was causing push notification to hit to the server.

Comment: how did u manage, in dev environment, to get ssl valid certif easily ? @kamalpanwar

Comment: I have same issue. I validated my certificate here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=example.com and it's valid. But still I don't receive any notification. I add that channel is created correctly (I go response form google API with id and other data). Any ideas?